# How to remove Invalid CSS after "": expected "{", was ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I restart my project after one month and get this error

```
Showing /home/abc/prij/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
Invalid CSS after "...���������������": expected "{", was ""

ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...���������������": expected "{", was ""):
2: <html>
3: <head>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
6:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
7: </head>
```

How I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Something's very wrong with one of your asset files. Are you sure you're not including a non-css file in your `application.css.scss`?

I'd narrow it down by removing some of your `requires` from `application.css.scss`. Hopefully this will isolate the problematic code, but it's tough to say much without more information.

Comment: only these line are in it  *= require_tree .
 *= require_self

Comment: Ok, so unless you've got something very strange in your `application.css.scss`, it's probably something in `require_tree`. Do you have any non js/coffeescript files in `app/assets/javascripts`?